# How to use Proxies and UUPS

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, proxy-contracts

I can't understand how to implement UUPS proxies. Should I create another proxy contract for this contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";

contract MyTokenV1 is Initializable, ERC20Upgradeable, UUPSUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {
    function initialize() initializer public {
      __ERC20_init("MyToken", "MTK");
      __Ownable_init();
      __UUPSUpgradeable_init();

      _mint(msg.sender, 1000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    /// @custom:oz-upgrades-unsafe-allow constructor
    constructor() initializer {}

    function _authorizeUpgrade(address) internal override onlyOwner {}
}
```

Or is this enough? If it is, how can I upgrade this contract?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to deploy a proxy contract. However, you don't need to do much as the proxy contract is now very minimal compared to the transparent proxy setup. You don't need to do anything else other than simply deploying the `ERC1967Proxy.sol` contract and linking your implementation.

Under the Open Zeppelin library you can find the [ERC1967 proxy](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967Proxy.sol). The proxy contract is deployed for you if you use the [Upgrades Plugin by Open Zeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/) or through [Ethereum Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/)

Comment: I noticed that doesn't have a __gap. Why does a similar contract in OZ's upgradeable contract have 2 __gap's (in Initializable and in ERC1967UpgradeUpgradeable). Also, does the implementation also need to inherent from anything other than initializable?